# resultado obtido não corresponde ao resultado real

Tags: c

Estou com dificuldades e nem sei como explicar, desculpem-me pelo titulo da dúvida, eis o código definido...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_JOGADOR       7//numero maximo de jogadores
#define MAX_BOLA_JOGADOR  2//numero maximo de bolas para cada jogador
#define MAX_BOLA          5//numero maximo de bolas para jogo

typedef struct BOLA BOLA;
typedef struct JOGADOR JOGADOR;
typedef struct CAMPO CAMPO;

struct BOLA {//cada bola
    int num_bola; //contem um numero de bola
};

struct JOGADOR {//cada jogador
    int num_jogador; //contem um numero de jogador
    struct BOLA bola[MAX_BOLA_JOGADOR]; //entre uma a duas bolas
    int qt_bola_jogador; //quantidade bola
};

struct CAMPO {
    struct JOGADOR jogadores[MAX_JOGADOR]; //contem no maximo 7 jogadores 
    struct BOLA bolas[MAX_BOLA]; //possui no maximo 5 bolas para cada jogo
};

struct JOGADOR novo_jogador; /*novo jogador*/
struct BOLA nova_bola; /*nova bola*/
struct BOLA *ptr_bola; /*apontador para  nova bola*/
struct JOGADOR *ptr_jogador; /*apontador para  novo jogador*/
struct CAMPO *ptr_campo; /*apontador para campo*/

void jogador_recebe_bola(void);
void criar_bola(void);
void criar_jogador(void);
```

nesta função cria os jogadores e adiciona ao ponteiro_campo, e está função funciona na perfeição

```
void criar_jogador(void) {

    int i, j; //identificador para incrementar criação de jogador

    //alocaçao de memoria para simular jogo
    ptr_campo = (CAMPO *) malloc(sizeof (ptr_campo));

    printf("\n--- JOGADOR ---\n");

    /* criar jogador*/
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < MAX_JOGADOR; i++) {
        novo_jogador.num_jogador++; //incrementa o numero de jogador
        novo_jogador.qt_bola_jogador = 0;
        ptr_jogador = &novo_jogador;
        ptr_campo->jogadores[i] = *ptr_jogador; //adicionar o jogador no campo
        printf(">> Criando jogador %d...\n\n", ptr_campo->jogadores[i].num_jogador);
        j++;
    }

    if (j == MAX_JOGADOR) {
        //criar bola
        criar_bola();
    }
}
```

Nesta função, cria-se a bola e adiciona-se ao ponteiro_campo, e está função também funciona corretamente

```
void criar_bola(void) {

    int k, m; //identificador para incrementar criação de bola

    printf("\n--- BOLA ---\n");

    /*cria bola*/
    for (k = 0, m = 0; k < MAX_BOLA; k++) {
        nova_bola.num_bola++; //incrementa o numero da bola
        ptr_bola = &nova_bola;
        ptr_campo->bolas[k] = *ptr_bola; //atribuir a baliza para cada jogador
        printf(">> Criar bola %d...\n\n", ptr_campo->bolas[k].num_bola);
        m++;
    }

    if (m == MAX_BOLA) {
        //criar bola
        jogador_recebe_bola();
    }
}
```

A minha dúvida é, nesta função jogador recebe bola, a função funciona quando o número de bolas for 1 e/ou 2 bolas, e se no caso for 3 bolas, como mostra na imagem abaixo, o código, em vez de dizer que o jogador tem bola nº3, diz que tem bola nº4 e quando for selecionado não faz nada...

```
void jogador_recebe_bola(void) {

    int recebe_bola = 0;
    int j, m;
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("\n--- JOGADOR RECEBE BOLA---\n");

    //faz um loop
    for (m = 0; m < MAX_BOLA; m++) {
        //captura a bola
        if (m + 1 == ptr_campo->bolas[m].num_bola) {
            //escolhe um jogador aleatorio
            recebe_bola = 1 + rand() % MAX_JOGADOR;
            ////faz um loop
            for (j = 0; j < MAX_JOGADOR; j++) {
                //captura o jogador a receber bola
                if ((j + 1 == ptr_campo->jogadores[j].num_jogador)
                        //jogador escolhido igual ao que está no campo
                        && (recebe_bola == ptr_campo->jogadores[j].num_jogador)) {
                    //escolhe o jogador x
                    printf(">> Jogador %d foi escolhido para receber bola %d...\n",
                            ptr_campo->jogadores[j].num_jogador, m + 1);
                    //recebe a bola do campo
                    ptr_campo->jogadores[j].bola[m] = ptr_campo->bolas[m];
                    //incrementa a quantidade de bola
                    ptr_campo->jogadores[j].qt_bola_jogador++;
                    //a bola nº y foi para jogador x
                    printf("\t>> Bola %d foi para jogador %d...\n",
                            ptr_campo->bolas[m].num_bola,
                            ptr_campo->jogadores[j].num_jogador);
                    //o jogador x tem bola nºy
                    printf(">> Jogador %d tem a bola %d...\n\n",
                            ptr_campo->jogadores[j].num_jogador,
                            ptr_campo->jogadores[j].bola[m].num_bola);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reveja o código [funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/C8nPFB)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, Renata. Seu código não compila (BOLA não tem atributo tipo_trajetoria). Se puder colocar uma amostra compilável e rodando em algum lugar ( Ideone.com , por exemplo), seria melhor.

Comment: @Pablo, só agora que consegui ver a sua notificação e de acto tens razao, eu coloquei o coidgo com pressa e nem deu para editar, mas já consegui modificar o que esta a mais e adicionei o que faltava e já fiz como indicaste, eis o [link do codigo funcionado no ideone.com](http://ideone.com/C8nPFB)

Comment: @Pablo, ainda não consegui como resolver esta dúvida, o que será que falta ou tem de errado?

Comment: Cheguei em casa agora. Já vou olhar.

Comment: Está por aí, @Renata?

Comment: @Pablo, só agora que consegui responder, ontem acabei adormecendo, na hora que respondeste a mensagem, eu já estava a dormir porque o nosso fuso horário é diferente, espero que não se importes?

Comment: Tudo bem. Veja a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui uma solução completa, mas descobri a causa do problema. Como eu não entendo a sua aplicação, não sei o que é intencional e o que não é, mas o que acontece é que, na terceira iteração, a variável em `ptr_campo->jogadores[j].qt_bola_jogador` e a variável `ptr_campo->jogadores[j].bola[m].num_bola` possuem o mesmo endereço de memória, então, incrementar uma incrementa a outra. Isso só acontece na terceira iteração, por algum motivo.

Então fica como exercício você descobrir o que está causando isso, mas como só pode ser em algum lugar que tem atribuição de endereços, não tá difícil pra quem entende o código, imagino.

Comment: por acaso tens razão, resolvi colocar a variável  `//ptr_campo->jogadores[j].qt_bola_jogador` em comentário e mostrou que o jogador tem bola 3 e mesmo assim, quando for o jogador com bola 3 for selecionado diz que tem 3 bolas e dá erro porque o jogador só pode ter até duas bolas e nesse caso, eu preciso apenas do numero da bola e não da quantidade de bola, o ideal é usar um ponteiro como fiz só que depois da terceira iteração, o numero da bola é atribuído a quantidade de bola, mas vou tentar para ver se consigo identificar, obrigado e pelo menos já tentei identificar o erro

Comment: a minha aplicação é simular uma partida de multibol, um jogo tipo de futebol mas é familiar em que cada jogador terá única baliza e depois são adicionadas as bolas no campo e cada bola será atribuída a um jogador selecionado aleatoriamente e tudo funciona até para simulação com duas bolas, agora quando for com 3 ou mais bolas, começa a fazer o que não devia, mas se está fazendo é porque a aplicação está recebendo está instrução em alguma parte do código

Comment: estive testar e acontece somente na terceira iteração e na quarta iteração da bola dá certo e quando o jogador com bola 4 for chamada dá certo, somente o jogador com bola 3 que diz que tem 4 bolas e esse 4 bolas, acho que será a soma "  `ptr_campo->jogadores[j].bola[m].num_bola  +  ptr_campo->jogadores[j].qt_bola_jogador++`; "